# Very Basic Misunderstanding of for loops in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop

I'm new to swift. can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here.

1.

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2]


for i in numbers{
    
    print(numbers[i],terminator: "")
}
```

why doesn't this just print the numbers in the array?

2.

Here I want to set the elements in the array to a random number from 0 to 2, and then print them.

```
for j in numbers{
        
    numbers[j] = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    print(numbers[j],terminator: "")
  
    }
```

this seems to work, but then if, outside of the for loop, I print them again:

```
for k in numbers{
    
    print(numbers[k],terminator: "")
}
```

It outputs different numbers, from 0 to 2

3.

OK so I try a different syntax:

```
for m in numbers{
    
    print(m,terminator: "")
}
```

now I get the same numbers every time and they are not from 0 to 2... I'm sure my mistakes are trivial but an explanation would help me out. Thanks.

Comment: `for i in numbers` sets `i` to each *element* of the array, not to the array indices.

Comment: So your first loop should simply be `for i in numbers { print(i) }` to get the expected result.

Comment: I suggest reading and running the code examples from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Answer (score 0):

to achieve what you expect, you need to loop over the `indices` of the array, like this:

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2]
for i in numbers.indices {  // <-- here
    print(numbers[i])
}
```

And as mentioned, read the basics of Swift.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  I'm gonna go and read the documentation.